# synchronized(obj) does not work ,why the result can be -1 or 0?

Tags: java, synchronized

synchronized(obj) does not work, why the result can be  -1 or 0?
when I use synchronized(this) it will be ok
so why will this happened

```
public class RunnableSales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ticket1 t = new Ticket1();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(t);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(t);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(t);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(t);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}

class Ticket1 implements Runnable {
    private int tick = 10;
    public void run() {
        Object obj = new Object();
        while (true) {
            synchronized (obj) {
                if (tick > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "sale:" + tick--);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the console print is:

```
Thread-1sale:10
Thread-2sale:10
Thread-3sale:10
Thread-0sale:9
Thread-2sale:8
Thread-3sale:7
Thread-1sale:8
Thread-0sale:8
Thread-1sale:6
Thread-0sale:3
Thread-2sale:5
Thread-3sale:4
Thread-1sale:2
Thread-0sale:1
Thread-2sale:0
Thread-3sale:-1
```

synchronized(obj) does not work, why the result can be  -1 or 0?
when I use synchronized(this) it will be ok
so why will this happened

Comment: `Object obj = new Object();` - Because of this. Every call to `run` generates a new `Object`, which is used for synchronization. Make this `Object` a `private final` field, and it should work.

Comment: The object You use for synchronization is created own for each thread, so every thread is synchronized on a different object. You want all threads synchronized on one object.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code, one finds that every call to `run()` generates a new `Object obj`, which is used for synchronization for this call only. Thus, there is actually no synchronization going on. The fix is quite easy: make `Object obj` a instance field. You should set it `final` to disallow reassignment (this can mess with synchronization).

The fixed version looks something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ticket1 t = new Ticket1(4);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(t);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(t);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(t);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(t);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

        try{
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
            t4.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}

class Ticket1 implements Runnable {
    private int tick = 10;
    private final Object obj = new Object();

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (obj) {
                if (tick > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "sale:" + tick--);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added code to explicitly wait for thread termination. You should always include this code to ensure all spawned threads are finished before the main thread exits. Output looks like this:

```
Thread-3sale:10
Thread-3sale:9
Thread-3sale:8
Thread-3sale:7
Thread-3sale:6
Thread-3sale:5
Thread-3sale:4
Thread-3sale:3
Thread-3sale:2
Thread-3sale:1
```

Notice that the final output shows a value of `1`. With respect to your program, this is correct since there is no output after `tick` was reduced to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you need make your lock object a class level variable rather than instantiating a new one inside the run() method. This way each thread access this class will be using the same instance of the lock object and not a newly created one in the run() method.

***Code***

```
static class Ticket1 implements Runnable{
    private final int tick = 10;
    private final Object obj = new Object();
    public void  run() {
        while(true)
        {

            synchronized(obj)
            {
                if(tick>0)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"sale:"+tick--);
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Ouptut***

```
Thread-0sale:10
Thread-0sale:9
Thread-0sale:8
Thread-0sale:7
Thread-0sale:6
Thread-0sale:5
Thread-3sale:4
Thread-3sale:3
Thread-3sale:2
Thread-3sale:1
```

Comment: A precursion to prevent bugs would be to declare `obj` as `final`.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @Turing85. I’ll update my answer to reflect that point.

Answer (score 0):

You thought the obj is as lock.
but when you start 4 thread, they will invoke run method, and each obj is created in each thread, so there is no meaning above code as a lock.
only tick is shared in 4 threads.
If you want working correctly, you need to declare obj as a class member variable.